# Trouble with applying modifiers

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

[image: head]

So I am sculpting a head, while following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmmSAsn_mOk. I created eyelids and used the mirror-modifier on them (also subsurf and solidify). Now it´s time to merge the eyelids with the head and sculpt on them to make them seamlessly connect to the head. The problem are the lower eyelids: the modifiers have Applying disabled; when I click on apply it says ***modifiers cannot be applied to multi user data***. I applied the upper lids just fine, not knowing how they differ from the lower ones. I never came across multi user data before neither at which point it was tackled; how can I fix the
lower eyelids in order to make their modifiers applyable? Here´s my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyg6tn0s4uclycm/head8.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a linked duplication of your eyelid object that is called *Sphere* and that is currently hidden. You can see in the *Object Data* panel that the shared mesh is called *Sphere.002*. You can't apply a modifier to an object that shares the same mesh as another object. You either need to make the linked duplication single (press on the *2* button), or *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*, or remove this object:

[image]

According to Kuboa, a new patch was accepted and added to Blender about this workflow. Now it will warn you that applying the modifier will make the object-data single-user, but it does apply it if you're OK with that. Available right now in 3.2 Alpha.

Comment: FYI and good news: two weeks ago a new patch was accepted and added to Blender about this workflow. Now it will [warn you that applying the modifier will make the object-data single-user](https://i.imgur.com/k2RpJJf.png), but it does apply it if you're OK with that. Available right now in 3.2 Alpha. (Maybe edit this in to your answer?)

Comment: oh ok thanks for the information  ;)

Answer (score 5):

Select the lower eyelid and go to the Object Data Properties tab (green triangle icon).

Next to the name of the mesh (Sphere.002), you can see the number 2 : this means the same mesh is used by another object (maybe you used Alt+D to duplicate it, or something like that.)

Just click the number to make it "single-user", that will fix the problem.

[image]

For your information, the other object using the same mesh is "Sphere", which is hidden in your scene.